# How to use destructuring to handle tuples readably?

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
fn f(x: &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32) {
    x.1 = x.1 + 11;
    x.0 = x.0 * 10;
    x
}
```

I would prefer:

```
fn f((x, y) as t: &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32) {
    x = x + 11;
    y = y * 10;
    t
}
```

Can readability like this be achieved?

Comment: You can use `fn f(&mut (ref mut x, ref mut y): &mut(i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32)` if you want to – not sure whether this is particularly readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can readability like this be achieved?

No, not in current Rust or in the planned future. *Syntax* similar to what you want already exists:

```
fn f(t @ &mut (ref x, ref y): &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32)
```

However, it isn't allowed:

```
error[E0007]: cannot bind by-move with sub-bindings
 --> src/main.rs:3:6
  |
3 | fn f(t @ &mut (ref x, ref y): &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32) {
  |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ binds an already bound by-move value by moving it

error[E0303]: pattern bindings are not allowed after an `@`
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 | fn f(t @ &mut (ref x, ref y): &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32) {
  |                ^^^^^ not allowed after `@`

error[E0303]: pattern bindings are not allowed after an `@`
 --> src/main.rs:3:23
  |
3 | fn f(t @ &mut (ref x, ref y): &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32) {
  |                       ^^^^^ not allowed after `@`
```

A tricky aspect of such code is that you'd have *mutable aliasing* — you can change the same value through both `t.0` and `x`. This is disallowed in Rust.

There's a slim possibility that the highly-anticipated *non-lexical lifetimes* (NLL) might allow the compiler to better reason about these cases, but I've not heard people taking about this specific aspect.

---

If you are willing to be flexible, there are some options:

```
fn f(t: &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32) {
    {
        let &mut (ref mut x, ref mut y) = t;
        *x = *x + 11;
        *y = *y * 10;
    }
    t
}
```

In nightly Rust, this can be simplified:

```
#![feature(match_default_bindings)]

fn f(t: &mut (i32, i32)) -> &(i32, i32) {
    {
        let (x, y) = t;
        *x = *x + 11;
        *y = *y * 10;
    }
    t
}
```

As I understand it, both of these cases should be improved by NLL.

Since you are taking and returning the same value reference, you could just stop returning it:

```
fn f(&mut (ref mut x, ref mut y): &mut (i32, i32)) {
    *x = *x + 11;
    *y = *y * 10;
}
```

Which can likewise be improved on in nightly Rust:

```
#![feature(match_default_bindings)]

fn f((x, y): &mut (i32, i32)) {
    *x = *x + 11;
    *y = *y * 10;
}
```

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for. Thank You.